# Dynamic Linking in Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I've built 2 android native libraries A and B such that library B depends on library A. My JNI native.cpp imports from library A. I've added the include files of my library A and library B and I've also added my .so files in my Java MainActivity.java as in

```
    System.loadLibrary("A");
    System.loadLibrary("B");
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
```

I was, however, getting undefined reference error. Hence I added .so files to the cmake linker as follows

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
            native-lib

            # Links the target library to the log library
            # included in the NDK.
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libA.so )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
            native-lib

            # Links the target library to the log library
            # included in the NDK.
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libB.so )
```

I still get the error even though some symbols might have been resolved as this is the static link while .so files need to be linked dynamically. Hence I wanted to know how I can link these dynamically and build my project with multiple dependencies.

Comment: Did you literally put "A" there? isn't your library called "libA.so"? You can only statically link to an archive file (.a), so this is still a dynamic link. Show us the remaining unresolved reference errors and tell us if they are part of A or B.

Comment: Yes, they are libA.so and libB.so. The unreferenced ones were from these libs itself.